# How to handle permissions for same non-root user on Docker & Host?

Tags: docker

### Background

We are dockerizing a product that have a application user (let's call it *appuser*), all the files & directories used by the application is owned by *appuser*.

In dockerized environment, dockers are run as *appuser*(non-root). Some files are present on linux host machine and they are bind mounted to docker containers. All bind mounted locations are owned by *appuser* on host.

### Issue

Now, the problem is *appuser* on host & *appuser* on containers won't have same UID, so we run into permission errors when we try to access bind mounted files.

### Solutions?

I see 2 approaches to this problem.
1. Make the UID of *appuser* on container same as that of on host. i.e. update the UID on docker entryscript.
2. Run the containers as root user.

**What would be the ideal way to handle this situation? Should we prefer running containers as root?**

## EDIT 1

We use docker-compose & have docker volumes shared between containers, the volumes are owned by *appuser*. Updating UID of *appuser* affects accessing docker volumes.

Currently we are using approach 1 from above & setting 777 to docker volumes.

## EDIT 2

Samples that show the described issue.

#### docker-compose

```
---
version: "3.4"
services:
  datacontainer:
    image: datacontainer
    container_name: datacontainer
    volumes:
     - type: volume
       source: commonJars
       target: /opt/company/product/java/lib

  product-server:
    image: product-server
    hostname: product-server
    container_name: product-server
    depends_on:
      - datacontainer
    environment:
      APPUSER_UID:
      APPUSER_GID:
    volumes:
     - type: volume
       source: commonJars
       target: /opt/company/product/java/lib
     - type: volume
       source: install
       target: /opt/company/product/install
     - type: volume
       source: product_temp
       target: /var/opt/company/product/tmp
     - type: bind
       source: /etc/opt/company/product
       target: /etc/opt/company/product
     - type: bind
       source: /var/opt/company/product/content-repo
       target: /var/opt/company/product/content-repo

    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
      - "8000:8000"

  product-loader:
    image: product-loader
    hostname: product-loader
    container_name: product-loader
    depends_on:
      - datacontainer
    environment:
      APPUSER_UID:
      APPUSER_GID:
    volumes:
     - type: volume
       source: commonJars
       target: /opt/company/product/java/lib
     - type: volume
       source: install
       target: /opt/company/product/install
     - type: volume
       source: product_temp
       target: /var/opt/company/product/tmp
     - type: bind
       source: /etc/opt/company/product
       target: /etc/opt/company/product
     - type: bind
       source: /var/opt/company/product/content-repo
       target: /var/opt/company/product/content-repo

volumes:
  commonJars:
    name: commonJars
  install:
    name: install
  product_temp:
    name: product_temp
```

#### server-entryscript

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -n "$APPUSER_GID" ]; then
  groupmod -g ${APPUSER_UID} appuser
fi
if [ -n "$APPUSER_UID" ]; then
  usermod -u ${APPUSER_UID} appuser
fi

chmod 755 /opt/company/product/bin/server-startup.sh

#script to start tomcat using jsvc as appuser
/opt/company/product/bin/server-startup.sh debug
```

Comment: One workaround is to make both UIDs the same (don't know if it's the only one). You should never run your containers as root in production (for security reasons).

Comment: That's the workaround we have currently applied, this just doesn't feel right.

Comment: In Linux, it's all about numbers when it comes to permissions. The only thing that matters are UID and GID. Perhaps it feels wrong, but I haven't run into other solutions.

Comment: Its not about just that. Updating UID impacts access to files present on docker volume as they are owned by the container user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, we can sync the user inside the container and on host by bind mounting */etc/passwd* and */etc/group*.

Compose syntax is,

```
 - type: bind
   source: /etc/group
   target: /etc/group
   read_only: true
 - type: bind
   source: /etc/passwd
   target: /etc/passwd
   read_only: true
```

Answer (score 0):

You could run docker with the [`--user` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#user):

```sh
docker run -d --user "$UID" ubuntu:latest printenv
```

In docker compose:

```
user: ${RUN_AS}
```

`RUN_AS=$(id -u):$(id -g); docker-compose up`

Comment: Updated question about the docker volumes we use. This solution will work for simpler cases.

Comment: @BalakumarSubramani I think it would help if you could share what your compose file and entrypoints look like. How are you mounting the volumes? Is the volume created by docker or managed by the host?

Comment: added sample compose & entryscript. Permission issue is see on docker managed volumes after UID is updated.

Comment: @BalakumarSubramani Why don't you use the `user` field in the compose file? Make each user run as the same group id and user id. If you want something that matches the host: `user: ${RUN_AS}`, and set environment variable `RUN_AS=$(id -u):$(id -g)`

Comment: user field can be used on compose to achieve the same functionality, but I want to find a solution other than running container with host user UID. Current problem is with docker volume which is owned by container user. As long as container is running with different UID, the problem can't be solved.

Comment: There are no options if you want to access files created from a container from your host also. Users must match or container must run as root, but then your files in the volumes will also be run as root. If files should be accessible both from the host and within containers, their uids need to match.

Comment: What about adding the UID created in container to the host user group? If this works, I don't need to run the container with host user and container user can access the files on host as it belongs to same group. I will try it out and update.

Comment: I would not recommend that, that's a major security vulnerability. The container should not manage users on the host.